# How to jump to original entry point in assembly?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, elf, packer

I am working on an elf packer program. I inject the executable code and then set the entry point to the offset of the executable code. The injected code in this code is just a breakpoint. My problem is that I want to have a piece of assembly code that jumps to the original entry point. I tried the inline methods but the problem was not solved.
I use ubuntu operating system and gcc and NASM.
My code is placed in two sections below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include "addSection.hpp"

inline bool isFileExists(const std::string &name)
{
    std::ifstream f(name.c_str());
    return f.good();
}

#define EI_NIDENT 16

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char e_ident[EI_NIDENT];
    uint16_t e_type;
    uint16_t e_machine;
    uint32_t e_version;
    uint32_t e_entry;
    uint32_t e_phoff;
    uint32_t e_shoff;
    uint32_t e_flags;
    uint16_t e_ehsize;
    uint16_t e_phentsize;
    uint16_t e_phnum;
    uint16_t e_shentsize;
    uint16_t e_shnum;
    uint16_t e_shstrndx;
} ElfN_Ehdr;

void PrintHeader(Elf32_Ehdr &h);
void PrintHeader(Elf64_Ehdr &h);
void PrintPHVec32(std::vector<Elf32_Phdr> &PHs32);
void PrintPHVec64(std::vector<Elf64_Phdr> &PHs64);

void PrintPHStr();
void PrintSHStr();

int main(int, char **)
{
    std::string pathFile{""};
    std::string sectionName{".text2"};
    // std::string pathBin {"/home/zch/C++/Test5/hello"};
    sectionName.reserve(100);
    std::string secTest;
    // Using a breakpoint as injected code
    secTest.push_back(0x90);
    secTest.push_back(0xcc);
    secTest.push_back(0x90);
    secTest.push_back(0x90);

    // std::ifstream in (pathBin);
    // if(in)
    // {
    //           std::ostringstream ss;
    //   ss << in.rdbuf(); // reading data
    //   secTest = ss.str();
    // }


    std::cout << "Enter the Path file: " << std::endl;

    std::getline(std::cin, pathFile);

    if (isFileExists(pathFile))
    {

        ElfN_Ehdr header;
        char answer;
        std::ifstream input(pathFile, std::ios::binary);

        std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});

        std::cout << "Add Section? " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> answer;

        if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            addSection(sectionName, secTest, buffer);
        }

        sectionName.clear();

        memcpy(&header, buffer.data(), sizeof(header));

        uint64_t offset = 0;

        if (header.e_ident[4] == 1)
        {
            Elf32_Ehdr header;
            memcpy(&header, buffer.data(), sizeof(header));

            PrintHeader(header);

            std::vector<Elf32_Phdr> PHs32(header.e_phnum);
            std::vector<Elf32_Shdr> SHs32(header.e_shnum);
            offset = header.e_phoff;

            for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_phnum; i++)
            {
                memcpy(&PHs32[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_phentsize);
                offset += header.e_phentsize;
            }

            PrintPHVec32(PHs32);

            offset = header.e_shoff;

            for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_shnum; i++)
            {
                memcpy(&SHs32[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_shentsize);
                offset += header.e_shentsize;
            }
            offset = SHs32[header.e_shstrndx].sh_offset;

            std::cout << "SHs32[header.e_shstrndx].sh_offset "<< SHs32[header.e_shstrndx].sh_offset << std::endl;

            PrintSHStr();
            for (auto &e : SHs32)
            {
                sectionName.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    // std::cout << i << " e.sh_name " << e.sh_name << std::endl;
                    if (buffer[offset + e.sh_name + i] != '\0')
                    {
                        sectionName.push_back(buffer[offset + e.sh_name + i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                std::cout << sectionName << " ";
                std::cout << e.sh_name << "\t\t" << e.sh_type << "\t" << e.sh_flags << "\t" << e.sh_addr << "\t" << e.sh_offset << "\t" << e.sh_size << "\t" << e.sh_link << "\t" << e.sh_info << "\t" << e.sh_addralign << "\t\t" << e.sh_entsize << std::endl;
                std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Elf64_Ehdr header;
            memcpy(&header, buffer.data(), sizeof(header));
            PrintHeader(header);

            std::vector<Elf64_Phdr> PHs64(header.e_phnum);
            std::vector<Elf64_Shdr> SHs64(header.e_shnum);
            offset = header.e_phoff;

            for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_phnum; i++)
            {
                memcpy(&PHs64[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_phentsize);
                offset += header.e_phentsize;
            }

            PrintPHVec64(PHs64);

            offset = header.e_shoff;

            for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_shnum; i++)
            {
                memcpy(&SHs64[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_shentsize);
                offset += header.e_shentsize;
            }

            PrintSHStr();
            offset = SHs64[header.e_shstrndx].sh_offset;
            for (auto &e : SHs64)
            {
                sectionName.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    if (buffer[offset + e.sh_name + i] != '\0')
                    {
                        sectionName.push_back(buffer[offset + e.sh_name + i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                std::cout << sectionName << " ";
                std::cout << e.sh_name << "\t\t" << e.sh_type << "\t" << e.sh_flags << "\t" << e.sh_addr << "\t" << e.sh_offset << "\t" << e.sh_size << "\t" << e.sh_link << "\t" << e.sh_info << "\t" << e.sh_addralign << "\t\t" << e.sh_entsize << std::endl;
                std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File Does Not Exist." << std::endl;
    }
}

void PrintHeader(Elf32_Ehdr &h)
{
    std::cout << "Magic: ";
    for (auto e : h.e_ident)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    if (h.e_ident[4] == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "32 Bit " << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "64 Bit" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Type:\t\t" << h.e_type << std::endl;
    std::cout << "machine:\t\t" << h.e_machine << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Version:\t\t" << h.e_version << std::endl;
    std::cout << "entry:\t\t" << h.e_entry << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phoff:\t\t" << h.e_phoff << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shoff:\t\t" << h.e_shoff << std::endl;
    std::cout << "flags:\t\t" << h.e_flags << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ehsize:\t\t" << h.e_ehsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phentsize:\t\t" << h.e_phentsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phnum:\t\t" << h.e_phnum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shentsize:\t\t" << h.e_shentsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shnum:\t\t" << h.e_shnum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shstrndx:\t\t" << h.e_shstrndx << std::endl;
}

void PrintHeader(Elf64_Ehdr &h)
{
    std::cout << "Magic: ";
    for (auto e : h.e_ident)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    if (h.e_ident[4] == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "32 Bit " << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "64 Bit" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Type:\t\t" << h.e_type << std::endl;
    std::cout << "machine:\t\t" << h.e_machine << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Version:\t\t" << h.e_version << std::endl;
    std::cout << "entry:\t\t" << h.e_entry << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phoff:\t\t" << h.e_phoff << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shoff:\t\t" << h.e_shoff << std::endl;
    std::cout << "flags:\t\t" << h.e_flags << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ehsize:\t\t" << h.e_ehsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phentsize:\t\t" << h.e_phentsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "phnum:\t\t" << h.e_phnum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shentsize:\t\t" << h.e_shentsize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shnum:\t\t" << h.e_shnum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shstrndx:\t\t" << h.e_shstrndx << std::endl;
}

void PrintPHStr()
{
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t\tProgram header" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "type\t"
              << "offset\t"
              << "vaddr\t"
              << "paddr\t"
              << "filesz\t"
              << "memsz\t"
              << "flags\t"
              << "align\t" << std::endl;
}
void PrintSHStr()
{
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t\tSection header" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==============================================================================================" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "name\t\t\t"
              << "type\t"
              << "flags\t"
              << "addr\t"
              << "offset\t"
              << "size\t"
              << "link\t"
              << "info\t"
              << "addralign\t"
              << "entsize\t" << std::endl;
}

void PrintPHVec32(std::vector<Elf32_Phdr> &PHs32)
{
    PrintPHStr();
    for (auto &e : PHs32)
    {
        std::cout << e.p_type << "\t" << e.p_offset << "\t" << e.p_vaddr << "\t" << e.p_paddr << "\t" << e.p_filesz << "\t" << e.p_memsz << "\t" << e.p_flags << "\t" << e.p_align << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }
}
void PrintPHVec64(std::vector<Elf64_Phdr> &PHs64)
{
    PrintPHStr();

    for (auto &e : PHs64)
    {
        std::cout << e.p_type << "\t" << e.p_offset << "\t" << e.p_vaddr << "\t" << e.p_paddr << "\t" << e.p_filesz << "\t" << e.p_memsz << "\t" << e.p_flags << "\t" << e.p_align << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is the addSection function

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <elf.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <zlib.h>

void addSection(std::string &sectionName, std::string &section, std::vector<unsigned char> &buffer)
{

    if (buffer[4] == 1) // if elf is 32 bit
    {
        Elf32_Ehdr header;
        uint64_t offset = 0;
        uint64_t SectionSize = section.length() + 1;
        uint32_t sh_name = 0;
        uint32_t target = 0;

        uint32_t PHTarget = 0;
        memcpy(&header, buffer.data(), sizeof(header));

        std::vector<Elf32_Phdr> PHs32(header.e_phnum);
        offset = header.e_phoff;

        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_phnum; i++)
        {
            memcpy(&PHs32[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_phentsize);
            offset += header.e_phentsize;
            if (PHs32[i].p_flags == 5)
            {
                PHTarget = i;
            }
        }

        PHs32[PHTarget].p_filesz += SectionSize;
        PHs32[PHTarget].p_memsz += SectionSize;
        for (uint32_t i = PHTarget + 1; i < PHs32.size(); i++)
        {
            if (PHs32[i].p_offset > PHs32[PHTarget].p_offset)
            {
                PHs32[i].p_offset += SectionSize;
                PHs32[i].p_vaddr += SectionSize;
                PHs32[i].p_paddr += SectionSize;
            }
        }

        offset = header.e_phoff;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < PHs32.size(); i++)
        {
            memcpy(buffer.data() + offset, &PHs32[i], header.e_phentsize);
            offset += header.e_phentsize;
        }

        std::vector<Elf32_Shdr> SHs32(header.e_shnum);

        offset = header.e_shoff;

        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < header.e_shnum; i++)
        {
            memcpy(&SHs32[i], buffer.data() + offset, header.e_shentsize);
            offset += header.e_shentsize;
            if (SHs32[i].sh_flags == 6 && SHs32[i].sh_offset >= PHs32[PHTarget].p_offset)
            {
                target = i;
            }
        }

        offset = SHs32[target].sh_offset + SHs32[target].sh_size;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < section.length(); i++)
        {
            buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset + i, section[i]);
        }

        offset += section.length();

        buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset, '\0');

        header.e_shoff += SectionSize;

        Elf32_Shdr sec;
        sec.sh_size = SectionSize;
        sec.sh_type = 1;
        sec.sh_flags = 6;
        sec.sh_name = SHs32[target].sh_name + sectionName.length();
        sec.sh_offset = SHs32[target].sh_offset + SHs32[target].sh_size;
        sec.sh_addr = sec.sh_offset;
        sec.sh_addralign = 1;
        sec.sh_link = 0;
        sec.sh_info = 0;
        sec.sh_entsize = 0;

        uint32_t targetSh_name = SHs32[target].sh_name;
        uint32_t entry = sec.sh_offset;

        for (uint32_t i = target; i < SHs32.size(); i++)
        {
            SHs32[i].sh_offset += SectionSize;

            if (SHs32[i].sh_name > targetSh_name)
            {
                SHs32[i].sh_name += sectionName.length() + 1;
            }
        }

        SHs32[SHs32.size() - 1].sh_size += sectionName.length() + 1;

        offset = header.e_shoff;

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < SHs32.size(); i++)
        {
            memcpy(buffer.data() + offset, &SHs32[i], header.e_shentsize);
            offset += header.e_shentsize;
        }

        offset = header.e_shoff + (header.e_shentsize * (target + 1));

        char str[header.e_shentsize];
        memcpy(&str, &sec, header.e_shentsize);

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < header.e_shentsize; i++)
        {
            buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset + i, str[i]);
        }
        header.e_shnum++;
        header.e_shstrndx++;

        offset = SHs32[SHs32.size() - 1].sh_offset;
        offset += targetSh_name + sectionName.length();

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sectionName.length(); i++)
        {
            buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset + i, sectionName[i]);
        }

        offset += sectionName.length();
        buffer.insert(buffer.begin() + offset, '\0');

        header.e_shoff += sectionName.length() + 1;

        header.e_entry = entry;
        
        memcpy(buffer.data(), &header, sizeof(header));

        std::ofstream fout("Test_bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

        std::copy(buffer.cbegin(), buffer.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(fout));
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

I tested this code

```
int entry = header.e_entry;

    asm volatile("jmp *%0"
                 :
                 : "r"(entry));
```

Comment: This is like your previous question, right? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346009/how-to-jump-to-original-entry-point-in-inline-assembly .  Where you were trying to jump to absolute address 0x10a0, but that's probably from a PIE executable and needs to be treated as a relative offset from the base address where it was relocated.  I think that's what `header.e_entry` is, like if you do `readelf -a` on `/bin/ls` or something, vs. if you run it under GDB and actually set a breakpoint on its `_start` to see an address like `0x555560a0` or something (assuming 32-bit code for `int` addr)

Comment: Yes, I deleted that question because it was not clear for the audience. I don't know how to add assembly code.

Comment: e_entry should be a relative offset once the file is loaded into memory. It won't be an absolute address every time, since ASLR can change the base address of the module each time its launched.

Comment: From my understanding, you would find the module base address once loaded in memory, then calculate the offset to the entry point then perform a relative jump.

Comment: @user21969376: Your last question already had a mostly-correct `asm()` statement to jump to an absolute address (with `jmp *%0` with a `"r"` register input constraint, just missing a `__builtin_unreachable()` after it to tell the compiler it didn't return.  Also a `"memory"` clobber since any previous assignments need to have happened.)  The reason it crashed is that you were jumping to the wrong address; you need to get the right absolute address according to where you unpacked it into memory and mapped the segments it according to the ELF program headers.

Comment: A packer will map the executable itself, so it automatically knows its base address. If, instead, you are infecting the program with a payload before jumping to the OEP (you seem to be adding a new section, thereby not preserving the original program), you are executing in the context of the "packed" program, so you can find its base address in the auxiliary vector. You can also use `dlopen` and `dlsym` or simply hardcode the difference between your new code address and the OEP.